# ARcore by google play services alternative

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, augmented-reality, arcore

the ARcore app on google play for android is now deprecated and so, I am not able to complete a Unity development course of mine on coursera which requires that. Some suggestions on how to get through?

I tried some tweaks in player settings and also installed ARcore and ARFoundation in Unity but still it requires Arcore app on my mobile to run but it's not available anymore. Also I am using a 3D template, not an AR core template from Unity coz the course required me to use that. I dont know if the template wasn't available then or which task should I not do if I use that template instead. I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Google Play services for AR app which takes care of the AR requirement for the Phone.( Its basically ARCore app repackaged with some extras). But you should have a AR supported device.

There are a few changes that you need to do to your 3D Unity project to make it usable for AR. If you use the AR template then Unity adds a Sample scene and the settings required for you to get started. Check this [AR foundation tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL21rXz2J9uIHv5_ktWrGvxM-Wabj8Qd5X) for better understanding.

Comment: nice playlist but my problem is not solved its different. I am not asking you to teach me AR. I know that. But why is it not running in my phone and how to make it run?